# Recursive sum, using Poisson distribution

Tags: r, recursion, infinite-loop

i am trying to build a recursive function in R,

```
H(x,t) = \sum\limits_{d=0}^{x} (Pr(D=d)*(h*(x-d)+H(x-d,t-1))) 
+ \sum\limits_{d=x+1}^{\infty} (Pr(D=d)*(p(*d-x)+ H(0,t-1)))
```

Where h,p are some constants, D ~ Po(l) and H(x,0) = 0, the are code i have done so far, gives an obvious error, but i can't see the fix. The code

```
p<- 1000 # Unit penalty cost for lost sales
h<- 10 # Unit inventory holding cost pr. time unit
l<- 5 # Mean of D
H <- function(x,t){
  if(t==0)(return(0))
  fp <- 0
  sp <- 0
  for(d in 0:x){
    fp <- fp + dpois(x=d,l)*(h*(x-d)+H(x-d,t-1))
  }
  for(d in x+1:Inf){
    sp <- sp + dpois(x=d,l)*(p*(d-x)+H(0,t-1))
  }
  return(fp+sp)
}
```

When i run this, the error is

```
Error in 1:Inf : result would be too long a vector
```

Which, seems obvious, so the question is, can anyone point me in the direction to redefine the problem, so i can get R to bring me a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will not work `for(d in x+1:Inf)` - you need to change `Inf` to some upper bound.

Comment: The issue is the sum have no upperbound, but as x -> Inf => Pr(D=d) ->0.. and i need a way to remove the 1:Inf in the loop but still summing Infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from `x+1:Inf` won't work. Since you're using poisson's pdf, you can just add a upper bound (why? think about the shape of the pdf and how small the values are at the right tail):

`for(d in x+1:100)`

which when ran for `H(20,2)` gives

```
[1] 252.806
```

when you increase it to

`for(d in x+1:500)`

then `H(20,2)` also gives

```
[1] 252.806
```

Comment: Given the original formulation in LaTeX shouldn't that be `for(d in (x+1):500`? This also means that the original statement `for(d in x+1:Inf)` should actually be `for(d in (x+1):Inf)` but that won't resolve the error message.

Comment: No - `(x+1):500` means from (x+1) to 500, but what if `x` is 600? Whereas `x+1:100` gives you the range `x+1` to `x+100` (i.e. 100 values), that is what you want.